# Mark an specific row in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, compare, conditional-statements

I have this table in Excel:

[image]

I need to compare the first row with the next rows assuming 2 conditions:

- The information in column A have to be the same as in column A of the first row.
- The number in column B have to be higher than in column B of the first row. But I only want to mark the next row with a higher value not all of them.

I want to get a table with the same format of the attached capture.

Thank you.

Comment: Your edit should be a new question actually.

Comment: Ok, I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a rule based on a formula, something like this:

```
=AND($A2=$A$1,$B2>$B$1,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A$1,$B$2:$B2,">"&$B$1)=1)
```

[image]